# How to add Leaflet Routing Machine control outside the map div

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

Leaflet [routing machine](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) container div is displayed on the map by default and I want to put this div below the map. Any clue to do this ?

Comment: would you please elaborate your question a bit more?

Comment: In this exemple : http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/ You can see that the result div is on the map. I want to hav a container that is below the map

Comment: so, do you want to add it outside the map div or it should be inside the map but at bottom of map?

Comment: I want to add it outside the map div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to add a leaflet control outside the map div. Here is a solution to it.

- Create a Div where you want to add your control and position it on page where ever you want
- Initiate your control and add it in a variable, like in this case I did

  ```
  var control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
      L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ]
  });
  ```
- Add your `control` to map like below

  ```
  control._map = map;
  var controlDiv = control.onAdd(map);
  ```
- Finally add your control to initially defined html div

  ```
  document.getElementById('controls').appendChild(controlDiv);
  ```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/Lon6nkg6/)

Answer (score 0):

I modified muzaffar solution, now it working much better.
Thank you muzaffar!

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(32.78186, -96.76612),
        L.latLng(32.77602, -96.80766)
    ],
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    reverseWaypoints: true,
    fitSelectedRoutes: true
});

var routeBlock = control.onAdd(map);    
document.getElementById('controls').appendChild(routeBlock);
```

Here if a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuzvac/kjwrutj2/)